# How to remove specific file from input file in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
function imageRemove(image) {
        var indx= $(image).parent().index();
        document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_FileUpload1").files[indx].remove();
        $(image).parent().remove();

    }

function preview(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            $(".images").remove();
            var filelist = input.files || [];

            if (filelist.length <= 10) {
                for (var i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
                    var filedr = new FileReader();
                    filedr.onload = function (e) {
                        var element = "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-2 images'>" +
                                          "<a class='thumbnail'><img class='test' src='" + e.target.result + "'/></a>" +
                                          "<span onClick='imageRemove(this)' class='imageRemove'>Sil</span>" + "<div class='clearfix'></div>" +
                                      "</div>";
                        $("#previews").append(element);
                    }
                    filedr.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                }
            }
            else {
                alert("Max 10 images");
            }

        }
    }

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" CssClass="fUp" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" onChange="preview(this)" maxRequestLength="2048" />
```

I want to remove selected file from "FileUpload1" control in jQuery. But `document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_FileUpload1").files[indx].remove();` not working. I know this is wrong but I don't know how to make.

Comment: The files object is read only, you can't add or remove files from it. You could of course add a condition in the loop to not preview an image, but it will still be uploaded

Answer (score 0):

you need to do

```
var files_ar = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_FileUpload1").files
files_ar.splice(indx,1)
```

and then just use the files_ar array instead.